# Error using sum() in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing homework assignment and I wrote the following code, which does what I want it to do:

```
A = [10, 25, 40]
B = [1, 15, 20]
R = [a + b for (a,b) in zip(A,B)]
print(R)
>>> [11, 40, 60]
```

However, when I change `a + b` to `sum(a,b)`, I get an error:

```
A = [10, 25, 40]
B = [1, 15, 20]
R = [sum(a,b) for (a,b) in zip(A,B)]
print(R)
>>> ... TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I understand that it looks like a stupid question, but I searched for it and couldn't find an answer. I am relatively new to Python, so don't quite understand what is going on. I am trying to iterate through a generator object that is produced by using `zip()` and that one is definitely not of type `'int'`.

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) for `sum`, you will find that its arguments don't work the way you're trying to use it.

Comment: @user2357112 You are right, I did look at it after posting the question and indeed was able to find the problem with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sum` takes an iterable as a parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). You should do the following:

```
R = [sum([a,b]) for (a,b) in zip(A,B)]
```

**If you only have two elements**, stick to the `+` operator. The `sum` function adds some noise and a small overhead compared to a simple `a + b` which is more intuitive.

Comment: Thank you, I went to documentation right after posting the question and found that I should have used `sum([a,b])`, which works perfectly.

Comment: No, you should use `a + b`. Why needlessly complicate it?

Comment: @Tibor I understand that `a+b` is the way to go, but since I am learning I was curious why it didn't work and hence posted my question, as it turns out, prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is a function to compute the sum of an iterable; if you want the sum of 2 elements, just use `+` as in your first case, or put `a` and `b` in an iterable (tuple: `(a, b)`, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Use map:

```
>>> A = [10, 25, 40]
>>> B = [1, 15, 20]
>>> map(sum, zip(A,B))
[11, 40, 60]
```

Using List Comprehension:

```
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(A,B)]
[11, 40, 60]
```

Comment: You submit another solution without explaining why the code of the OP is wrong. Please take the habit to at least says why the original code does not work :)

Comment: @MaximeLorant Others have explained about it, no need to repeat , so i have just given another way :), you only have explained about it in your answer

Answer (score 1):

`zip` takes iterables and returns an iterable of tuples containing `i`-th element from each argument. In your case, that'd be the equivalent of

```
zip(A,B) -> [(10,1), (25,15), (40,20)]
```

By writing

```
[  ... for (a,b) in zip(A,B)]
```

you are unpacking the tuple into two bound variables with names `a` and `b`. Now `a` and `b` are `int`s because the elements of `A` and `B` were ints. Use a plus operator to add those two ints together or

```
[ sum(tup) for tup in zip(A,B)]
```

if you want to sum the whole tuple without unpacking explicitely.

Comment: Change ur statement, zip can take any number of iterables

Comment: Fixed, but I meant in OP's specific example.